# Partial update of a crossrider extension

Tags: updates, crossrider

After publishing a new version of our extension to production, we sometimes see a weird behavior:
The extension on the browsers seems to be only partly updated (after given some time).
Our internal version number (part of our code) shows in such cases a previous version number, although some features and resources from the newer version already exist.

We have seen this occasionally in all browsers and on different operating systems.

Any idea why is that and what can be done?

Note: our extention.js and popup.html files are about 380kb (I don't know if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I don't know the specifics of your scenario, in general, updates are automatically checked for and pulled if required by the extension several times a day. If there is anything that interrupts the process such as connectivity problems, then a partial update may occur though there are mechanisms in place to try and protect against this. Also, note that resources update if there are changes to one of the core files (extension.js or background.js).

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]